# Gradle Terminal is not showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, terminal, android-gradle-plugin

The Gradle Terminal (also called Gradle Command Line) is not showing in my android studio, I have Android Studio version 1.3.1 and I have been searching for how to view the terminal for over an hour now and all I get are tutorials about how to use it and not how to show it so that I can eventually use it.
Anybody got a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I did not find any solution to open the Gradle Terminal in Android Studio 1.3.1, I found an alternative way that lets me execute Gradle tasks outside the terminal. Go to Gradle console -> Gradle icon that says Execute Gradle task -> a pop-up opens -> attach your project -> write the task in the second field -> ok.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if there is such thing in Android Studio.
There is `Gradle console` and `Terminal` for sure.

Anyways, there is `Find Action...` command and you can use it to find "all" kind of things in Android Studio.

Just go to the `Help` menu and you will find it there.  Here it's second menu option right after `Search`.  Use this option to search for commands/features in Android Studio, like on the following image:

[image: "Find Action" in action]

As you can see there is `Gradle Console` available and if you search for the *terminal* you will find `Terminal` option as well.  But no *Gradle Terminal* or *Gradle Command Line* ;-)

Comment: I found the terminal and I am pressing on it, but nothing happens.
Do you know if I can run gradle tasks from the Gradle Console?

Answer (score 6):

check View - > Tool Windows - > Terminal in android studio

Comment: Nothing there, I am using Android Studio version 1.3.1

Comment: This is no the Gradle Console, but the OS terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Click "View" option top on the Android studio then click "Tool Windows" after "Gradle"; that's it.
View--->Tool Windows---->Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the gradle build *output*, you need to activate the "Build" Tool window.

Click `View`->`Tool Windows`->`Build`

Answer (score -1):

click search on right side of ide - > type gradle - > gradle window will be opened

Very simple

Comment: That Gradle window is the task view, but not a Gradle Terminal.